# why between nginx/nginx upstream use http/1.0?

Tags: nginx, keep-alive, http-1.1, http-1.0

I have 3 server:
A(nginx)-->B(nginx)-->C(nodejs),

When i access A or B,chrome use http/1.1+keepalive by default.

I do not set "proxy_http_version 1.1;" and  proxy_set_header Connection "";

But between A and B,NGINX use http/1.0 by default。That is like:

**client** --> **nginxA(upstream to b)** --> **nginxB(upstream to c)** -->**C (nodejs)**

**http/1.1** --> **http/1.0** --> **http/1.1** --> **nodejs**

My questions is :
why nginx use http/1.1 for upstream by default，between nginx and nginx, upstream use http/1.0 ?

THX.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't configure nginx to use http/1.1 for node?

Comment: Yes,I'm sure.I use Tengine-2.2.0(based Nginx-1.8.1).Thank you for your quick reply.

Comment: I think i find my result:http://serverfault.com/questions/442960/nginx-ignoring-clients-http-1-0-request-and-respond-by-http-1-1 thanks~

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nginx since version 1.1.4 supports HTTP/1.1 when connecting to upstream servers. You just need to set configuration parameter `proxy_http_version 1.1` (1.0 is the default value).
see http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_http_version

Comment: then a question is why they have the proxy http verison default to 1.0 and not 1.1